# HTML paragraph new line if no place in inline-block div

Tags: html, css

I have in div two divs with floats (left and right). In right div there are paragraphs. All that two divs have inline-block display. If paragraphs in right div too long, then right div jump over the left, and set to display block.

I'm want to paraghraps do new line if it too long.

Code:

```css
.left {
  margin: 30px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.right p {
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="{url}">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <p>p3</p>
    <p>p4</p>
    <p>p5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When text in paragraph too long:

```css
.left {
  margin: 30px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.right p {
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.left img {
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://monitorgame.com/m/games/001.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <p>p3</p>
    <p>p4</p>
    <p>p5 text text text text text text lalalalalalalalalalalallalalallalalalala</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allocate space for them. I like using floats in these instances, so for example you could add float:left width: 50% to each one, something like that.

```
 .left {
 margin: 30px;
  float: left;
 width: 50%;
}

.right {
 float: left;
 width: 50%
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

You already had the float, you just needed to specify the width. They could be static too not % if you want, but if the static sizes don't fit in the screen they will break like your example.

see working here  : https://jsfiddle.net/3LtLuxbc/3/

Just a note on the fiddle - I changed your img size to with 100% and removed the border so it would scale , you can change that to suit your design.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to the right div. This will force the text to wrap. Without a specified width, div will increase in size until reaching max size of wrapper div or page